# View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN not working

Tags: android, android-theme, android-fullscreen

I want to make a completely transparent status bar and content behind it.

My device runs with 24 API.

I use this code (in my AppCompatActivity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
```

but it doesn't make any effect, my content is still UNDER the status bar;
I also tried to put `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in my root view, but it didn't help either.
I also tried to put the code after setContentView, still no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

replace this with your code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
{
   View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
   v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
   View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
   decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function `callFullScreen`

```
public void callFullScreen(Activity activity)
{
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

You can remove some lines to get required result, and finally call `callFullScreen();` inside `onCreate`